# How to add subviews to a tableview cell dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I created a custom tableview cell in IB. I add a scroll view as a subview of the cell's contentView, and create the IBOutlet in the tableview cell subclass, and make the connection. My problem is, I want to add subviews to the cell dynamically, but when I did this in code, nothing happens. The cell is rendered successfully, but the scrollView has nothing to show (no subviews on it).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // deque the cell
    // create some label depending on the MODEL object
    // (this is done by code, not in IB. because the label is content-based)
    // we don't know how many labels in advance
    [cell.scrollView addSubview: label];  // not working !!
    ...
    return cell;
}
```

But if I add the subviews in IB (which means the subviews are pre-defined), it works.

Is there any ways to add the subviews to a cell dynamically ? Or maybe I put the code in the wrong place ?

Comment: Are you sure `cell` object is of your custom cell class object. It also has `scrollView` as a `IBOutlet` property in that custom table cell class with proper connection ?

Comment: where is the declaraton of `label`

Comment: please add the complete code in you `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. It is not clear if you are using a custom cell or not? Does your cell have a scrollView ? Did you try adding your label to cell.contentView??

Comment: @Tushar J.  Yes, pretty sure.

Comment: @colin thanks for your valuable comments.. i updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 8, 130, 30)];
label1.text = @"any text";
label1.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[cell addSubview:label1];// first try adding to cell
```

if you need to add as subview of `cell.scrollView`

```
NSLog(@"scrollView %@",cell.scrollView);//it should not be nil
```

check scrollView content size and frame

For dynamic string this will also help you

```
NSString *string = @"This is the text";
CGSize stringsize = [string sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]]];
UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 8, stringsize.width+30/*you have to adjust 30 as u required*/, 30)];
label1.text = string;
label1.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
cell.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(label1.frame.size.width+30/*you have to adjust 30 as u required*/, label1.frame.size.height);
[cell.scrollView addSubview:label1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all of the responses.

This is really embarrassing. The problem is I mis-config the label property, make the label text color white, but somehow the scrollView background is also white. So I can't see the labels, but actually they are already there.

All the responses are helpful, but @Shebin's answer gave me the hint to check the color, so I think I should mark his answer as the best.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add proper constraints on your sub views. The scrollable size of a UIScrollView is computed based on the constraints of its subviews. Please ensure that constraints on the content view of your cell is properly added.

And if you are not setting constraints on your subview like label etc. then its `intrinsicContentSize` is used.